# Pandas: Can't append and reassign to a DataFrame inside a function

Tags: python, pandas

What I want to do is to append to a DataFrame that is passed as a parameter to a function kind of what is done in the following code by function `f`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[(0,1), (0,1)], columns=['a', 'b'])

df
Out[58]: 
   a  b
0  0  1
1  0  1

def f(df):
    df['a'] = 1 # The first column will be modified
    # However the following will have no effect
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[(0, 1)], columns=['a', 'b']))


f(df)
df
# As we see `append` didn't have an effect on the df
Out[61]: 
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  1
```

As we see from the code above, `append` has no effect if the DataFrame is not returned. Is there any reason why this happens?

**Edit:**

I think I understood the reason after I wrote the question. Since `append` creates a new object if the new object is not returned, then the assignment

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[(0, 1)], columns=['a', 'b']))
```

will only pass the new DataFrame to the copy of the reference to the `df`, the copy that is generated by the function call, and *not to the original `df`*. Thus, the new DataFrame gets lost.

Comment: append does not operate inplace. It creates a new Dataframe. If you will not use the returned object you will remain with the same Dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you forget `return df`:

```
def f(df):
    df['a'] = 1 # The first column will be modified
    # However the following will have no effect
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[(0, 1)], columns=['a', 'b']))
    return df

print (f(df))
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  1
0  0  1
```

Or better:

```
def f(df):
    df['a'] = 1 # The first column will be modified
    return df.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[(0, 1)], columns=['a', 'b']), ignore_index=True)

print (f(df))
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  0  1
```

I think if check [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) it return new `object`, so `return` is necessary.

Comment: Yes I did it on purpose, because I am trying to see if passing the DataFrame by reference can have an effect when it is reassigned. As it says in the post _"As we see from the code above, append has no effect if the DataFrame is not returned. Is there any reason why this happens?"_

Comment: I think if check [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) it return new object, so `return` is necessary

Comment: Makes sense, so then the new object is _volatile_ and gets lost despite it is assigned to the function parameter

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot explain it better, but as explain [AndreyF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090794/pandas-cant-append-and-reassign-to-a-dataframe-inside-a-function/42090833#comment71351816_42090794) there is no inplace parameter, so this function cannot works inplace.

Comment: I think I found the answer after reflecting a bit, see my edits. Thank you anyway